# How to find out the SQLITE query result is NULL?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

I've used the following method in my app,

```
-(int) getMax:(NSString *)subItemName second :(int) tableID
{
    int count1=0;
    sqlite3_stmt *statement;
    NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Select MAX(NoOfItems) from billTable where SubItemName='%@' AND TableID='%d'",subItemName,tableID];
    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(_database, [query UTF8String], -1, &statement, nil)== SQLITE_OK) {
     while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
            count1 = [[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)]intValue];
        }

        sqlite3_step (statement);
    }
    return count1;
}
```

As you can see that the my query will return the no of rows (an integer), suppose if my query returns a `NULL` value(if there is no such exists for the where clause condition in my database it returns `NULL` value. How to check it returns `NULL` after the query has been executed?

Comment: Why do you call `sqlite3_step` in two places? The 2nd one should be `sqlite3_finalize`.

Comment: And do not build queries using `stringWithFormat:`. Make proper use of the `sqlite3_bind_xxx` functions to bind the values to the query.

Answer (score 1):

You can call [sqlite3_column_type()](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/column_blob.html) to find out what type a column value has:

```
if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(_database, [query UTF8String], -1, &statement, nil)== SQLITE_OK) {
    if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
        if (sqlite3_column_type(statement, 0) == SQLITE_NULL)
            count1 = -1; // or whatever
        else
            count1 = sqlite3_column_int(statement, 0);
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
}
```